# Google-served ads obscuring content (admob)

Tags: react-native, admob

I've developed an app for IOS and android using react native and expo. To show ads I'm using the lib: react-native-google-mobile-ads

But unfortunately google has restricted my ads (android only) due the issue Google-served ads obscuring content.

I have three banners (ANCHORED_ADAPTIVE_BANNER) and one rewarded ad implemented (play button "Extra Baum"), see screenshots:

[image]
[image][image]

I cannot see / find the banner which obscures content in my app. Maybe someone of you can tell me?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I’m facing the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your app complies with policy and doesn't obscure content. Same has happened to me and I believe it's because of a fault with Google's detection system. Google can't identify elements of a native app, so it thinks the whole app is a UI element - you can see this happening in the pre-launch report when you submit an app. You have to hope that a human will review the policy breach and correct it manually, which is unlikely because the humans appear to be AI that work on the same detection system. I suggest finding an alternative like AppLovin, or injecting your own ad system in that cross-promote your apps or link to Amazon banners.

Comment: How do you understand that it compiles with policy and doesn't obscure content? Should I add the vertical padding for banners or not? If I add `8dp` how do I know if it will be enough? Is there any official information about it? What value should I set - 8, 16, 24, 32?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your design I can see how it might look like the banner ad is hiding some of the weather in your scrolling list.  I think if you were to put some padding around the ad and give that whole banner section the same green background color as the rest of your app it wouldn't look like the ad itself is covering the scrollable area.

Comment: The banners are adaptive and fill the available width. You have no control over the colour of the ads either.

Comment: "Some padding". What does it mean? If I add `8dp` how do I know if it will be enough? Is there any official information about it? What value should I set - 8, 16, 24, 32?